# How I can open tree view in pgadmin 4

Tags: postgresql, treeview, pgadmin

[its my PgAdmin 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt2cx.png)

I dont know how , but tree view closed.
how I can open without losing data in servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tree view is on your Browser tab. Simply click on the Browser tab and drag it to the left/right where you would like to have it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File->Reset Layout. It will reset pgAdmin to default layout. No data will be lost.